# How to get Title of Home Page to Appear on Page

Tags: title, homepage

How can I get the Title of a Home Page to appear?

I am using the Quark "out-of-the-box" **Front Page Template**.

Home Page "view source":

```
<article id="post-1" class="post-1 page type-page status-publish hentry">
    <div class="entry-content">
```

Inner Page "view source":

```
<article id="post-2" class="post-2 page type-page status-publish hentry">
        <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Inner Page</h1>
                </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$id_frontpage = get_option('page_on_front');
echo get_the_title( $id_frontpage );
```

If you need the ID of the page that displays posts use `get_option('page_for_posts')`.

Answer (score 0):

To return the name of your page, simply:

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo get_the_title( $ID ); ?></h1>
</header>
```

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: Ok, thanks @Archie22is. Would you happen to know why the page title does not appear when a page is set to "Font Page" in the Settings > Reading ? Is that a limitation in WordPress?