# How to output the title of the blogs home page

Tags: wp-query, title, homepage, get-the-title

I am using a static frontpage and a page for my blogposts. In my header.php I want to display the title of the selected page of my blogposts.

For example:

```
<?php 
if( is_home() )
 echo '<h1>' . get_the_title() . '</h1>';
?><nav> 
... 
</nav>
```

But of course  `get_the_title()` returns the first element of the displayed posts and not of the page itself.

How can I display the title of the assigned home page?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204295/how-to-get-title-of-home-page-to-appear-on-page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use the queried object to return the title of the page used as blogpage

You can use the following: (*Require PHP 5.4+*)

```
$title = get_queried_object()->post_title;
var_dump( $title );
```

Comment: Why does this return `string(55) "Title of the static page"`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the id from options and then echo the title using that id.

```
// Blog Page
$page_for_posts_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );

echo get_the_title($page_for_posts_id);

// Front Page
$frontpage_id = get_option('page_on_front');

echo get_the_title($frontpage_id);
```

Comment: Why would you want to make an unnecessary db call to get the page id while you already have everything available in the queried object. Unless I misread the question and the OP needs the know the page name and display it on all pages, then your solution would be the preferable one ;-)

Comment: I would just consider this another 'option' if you will. ;) One that doesn't come w/a php req.

Comment: Well, if you are not running atleast PHP5.5, you have serious issues. With upgrades already stopped on PHP 5.5, you should be using PHP 5.6.  ;-)

Comment: Hi jgraup, thanks for the effort, but I prefer Pieters answer for the reasons he mentions. But yours would work too.

Comment: Jip, I know. *One that doesn't come w/a php req*. As I said, if you are not at least running 5.6, you are stuffed. Always better to run the newest. Most crap hosts out there are stuck at 5.3 anyways, so I've added the notice for people on crap hosts, hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

A note for those thinking of using @pieter's solution on index.php - On index.php, you'll want to check that a static Page is set to show the posts in Setting > Reading. The `is_home()` conditional does not work on index.php, so you do need to check the option is set:

```
<?php
// See if "posts page" is set in Settings > Reading
$page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ); 
if ($page_for_posts) { ?>
    <header class="page-header">
        <h1 class="page-title" itemprop="headline">
            <?php echo get_queried_object()->post_title; ?>
        </h1>
    </header>
<?php } ?>
```

This check is important because index.php is also called when "Front Page Displays > Your latest posts" is set. In that case, `get_queried_object()->post_title;` will return an object-not-found error.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>

    <section class="hero">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

            <h1>news, and personal musings</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is just about the home page tile, why don't you hard code the title?

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>
   <h1>Your blog posts page title</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why would you want to hardcode stuff. This is messy because you would need to change everything manually each time you set another page as blogpage

Comment: I think so too. In my case, I didn't know, what the client wants to call this page later on. In the layouts he sends its called one time "Blog", the other time "Agenda", in order to avoid long talkings and so on, I want it automatic so he can easily change to the name he prefers without asking me.

Comment: The blogpage (home())  is fairly standard imho. And it is exactly the same work whether you change it in the page title or the header. However I do understand that a client would prefer to change the title on the page.

Comment: @IXN *The blogpage (home()) is fairly standard imho*. Not if you have set a static frontpage and a blogpage, then it is not standard anymore ;-)